# Why performance of this query deteriorates over time?

Tags: oracle, query-performance, performance-tuning

I have a 1 million row table in oracle 19c. I am running this query. Table has an index on ID column, stats are up to date.

```
select <columns>
from (select <columns> from <tableA> where ID > 42000 order by ID ASC) 
where rownum < 1001;
```

Next one will be

```
select <columns>
from (select <columns> from <tableA> where ID > 43000 order by ID ASC) 
where rownum < 1001;
```

This is not efficient, the `ID` is different each time and the query has to loop 1000 times to cover 1 Million rows in the table. Initially for few minutes the query is super fast, several milliseconds, then   it starts to slow down and the last few iterations take over 30 seconds per execution.

How can I rewrite or speed it up ? I gathered stats, increased SGA, shared pool size etc.

Comment: Why are you trying to return results in 1000 row pages if you are intending to fetch every row from the table?  The fastest way to do that would generally be to simply write a simple `select *`query with no predicate (presumably enabling parallelism if that wasn't automatically done for that query).

Comment: Use a bind variable instead of a literal for the ID starting point so you don't have to hard parse each batch. Have you checked the execution plan? I would expect: index range scan (filtering > :start_point), and a count stop key after access to the table.

Comment: You may also want to check the query plan used. Most likely it does not use the index but does a full table scan for each round - which explains the perceived gradual slowdown. 
It also looks like the IDs are a continuous growing number ? If so why not fetch the rows using à BETWEEN filter ? That is more likely to use the index and provide constant performance. 

But as said, I also don’t understand the need to process that table in sets of 1000 rows at a time instead of just reading it completely in one step and letting the application care about the splitting.

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)